how can i turn off the node tabs in blender 4.3.0

that I'm used to blender 3.0 and older it slows me down with this?

Hello. I see three solutions. Go back to the previous Blender version, hack the source code to revert it back for yourself, or use a custom node group that will have these parameters exposed directly.

@Gorgious what??

@Dragonred don't expect someone will elaborate if you don't care to even write what part is confusing you.

oh sorry i didn't know what he means by hacked sorry

I meant forking Blender's source code to maintain your own which is a massive endeavour. I would suggest going for the 3rd option ;)

It doesn't answer your question but you can also reduce the node with H or Ctrl H

I checked if maybe Python API allows to move sockets to the top level of the tree, but couldn't find any option, and move function reports an error, saying it doesn't work for builtin nodes.

It doesn't seem possible, that said if you press H or CtrlH or H then CtrlH you'll have the following results:



